# how to modify system variable path win7 64bit emgu cv

Tags: c#, emgucv

my system is windows x64 operating system. then when I set system variable path how to do it. whether I need to set C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.4.10.1940\bin\x64 or C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.4.10.1940\bin\x86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Environment` class.  It has methods to retrieve and set environment variables:

```
string path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", path + @";C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.4.10.1940\bin\x64");
```